# looping through pages and updating ACF field data for each inside of a function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, loops, advanced-custom-fields

Having a bit of an issue and hoping for some help. Basically I am triggering a function on `acf/save_post` action for a custom post type called '**settings**'. So if '**settings**' is saved or updated I want to loop through all existing pages and update a ACF field for each page with a specific piece of data.  My loop is below.  I've been fighting with this thing all weekend but it doesn't seem to update any pages. Any help would be huge! Thanks!

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page' ) );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    global $post;  
    $pageID = $post->ID;
    update_field('temp_post_data','test' , $pageID);
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update field on current page.

Try this

```
function my_custom_function() {
  $pages = get_pages(); // get all pages
  foreach($pages as $page):
    // error_log($page->ID); // debug if needed
    update_field('temp_post_data','test' , $page->ID); //for each page we are updating  field
  endforeach;
}
```

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!!